# How to redirect stderr on launch *without* redirecting stdin and stdout?

Tags: windows, platform-sdk

In Windows, I'd like to use CreatePipe and CreateProcess to launch a process, and capture the text written to stderr.

There is sample code at MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

My problem is I want to redirect and capture STDERR, but leave STDIN and STDOUT alone.  Let them still be bound to the child process's console window.  (If the child process is a console process and not a window process.)

If I follow the example code, and set STARTUPINFO.hStdError to my pipe handle, and set STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput and STARTUPINFO.hStdInput to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, then the child process has INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE to stdin and stdout; all reads fail; all printf's go nowhere; and the console window is completely blank.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
STARTUPINFO.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

Alternatively, if you can't give the parent process a console, you could set hStdOutput and hStdInput to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and call through cmd.exe as follows:

```
cmd /c "subprocess.exe > con < con"
```

Note that [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SHGFI_EXETYPE` will tell you whether the executable is a console application or not if you don't already know.

Comment: I should have been more clear:  The process doing the launch doesn't have a console.

Comment: You'll need to allocate one first using AllocConsole.  Then you can use GetStdHandle as shown.

Comment: So basically, there's no way to redirect individual streams.  It's either all or none?

Comment: That's not quite how I'd put it, but basically yes.  If you specify `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` you have to provide all three handles.  If for some reason you can't allocate a console for the parent process, you could work around the problem by using cmd.exe as an intermediary.